# vb.net Web Browser Login

Tags: vb.net

Hello i am Making an application To login To Nexon.net , I cant Get it to Work Because The Text Fields Dont Seem To have ID to Use `GetElementByID` ....

This is The webpage http://www.nexon.net/

and this is the Code i tried But It doesnt Work =/

```
Dim Username, Password As String
    Username = TextBox1.Text
    Password = TextBox2.Text


    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("userID").SetAttribute("value", Username)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", Password)
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gnt_login_submit").InvokeMember("click")
```

I tried to use this to verify login But Does not work

```
If (Not WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("gnt_play_button") Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox("Incorrect Username/password , ", 0, "Login error!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Document.All` instead:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("userName").SetAttribute("value", Username)
WebBrowser1.Document.All("passwordName").SetAttribute("value", Password)
WebBrowser1.Document.All("gnt_login_submitName").InvokeMember("click")
```

Instead of `id`, pass the element's `name` attribute value to `All` like shown above.

Comment: Thanks For your answer but Keeps Giving me NullReference Error =/

Comment: This is How The login Form Looks Like , "<input type="text" name="userID">"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine but the prob. is you are sending these values when page is loading

fill this in

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("userID").SetAttribute("value", "User")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "Pass")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gnt_login_submit").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub
```

and check

Comment: use any thing like Getbetween if you want to check that user has Logged in or not or its bad username like check in the source of the webpage if the User has logged in then there will be some text like Welcome or Username search for it and then show Msgbox("Correct Login") 

& Also i will give you a little advice Please try to use HttpWebRequest its fast and easy and will give you same Response like if you want to check that user has logged in or not etc..

Comment: i tried Doing that but It doesnt seem To Recognize ID or Text In the Webpage